# How to ask in Chinese Mandarin: What do you want me to say?

Tags: phrase, sentence

When someone tells me to say something and I don't know what to say, I want to ask that person "What do you want me to say?"

How can I ask that question in Chinese Mandarin? Below is what I come up with, not sure if they are correct.

你想我说什么？

or

是什么你想我说?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one sounds just fine. The "what" part is the object of the sentence. In forming a question in Chinese, the general position of the SVO doesn't change. The second one looks like using Chinese words to fit into an English word order.

Affirmative sentence: 你想我说 "XYZ" .

Question: 你想我说什么？ - Question word "什么" replaces "XYZ" .

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a boy girl argument! Oh, the agony, and the delight!

你想让我说什么？

Answer (score 0):

You can say whether 你想我说什么？ or　你要我说什么？